# How to make the height of a div box depend on how much text is in it

Tags: css, html, text, height

I fixed the width to 900px but I want the height to depend on the amount of text and objects in it. Is there a way to do this, this is the CSS I currently have for the div

```
#mainbox {
padding:0;
margin:0 auto;
width:900px;
border:solid 2px
```

}

Comment: Remember to set the width of you're div then set height: auto; this will work fine :)

Comment: @JakeMclaughlin Actually, setting the height is the opposite of what he wants to do. Also, he already has set the width in his example.

Answer (score 3):

You would do this by not setting a height at all which is equivalent to `height: auto;`. By default the div will wrap the content. If it's not doing that then post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Mostly true, but if other settings mess up the document flow, this can make `height:auto` not work as expected. Since the code he provided doesn't specify height, it's likely that there is other code influencing his `div` and breaking the `auto` adjust of the height.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have does that. [Here's a JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/3C9W8/). The only thing I changed is I made your ID into a class, since I was putting multiple `div`s in there.

If you don't specify a height, and the `div` has not been set to `position: absolute`, `position: fixed` and its content is in normal flow (e.g. not `float:left` or `float:right` or with a weird `position`) then the height should adjust fine with the content.